# Why can't remove the user password for pdf file?

Tags: pdf

Install tools for crypt and decrypt pdf file:

```
sudo apt install -y pdftk
```

Crypt a pdf file with it:

```
pdftk inputfile.pdf output outputfile.pdf user_pw mypass
```

Now i have to input `mypass` to open the `outputfile.pdf` with some pdf viewer,delete the `inputfile.pdf`.

Try to decrypt the already crypted file  `outputfile.pdf` with `pdftk`:

```
pdftk outputfile.pdf output decrypt.pdf user_pw mypass
Error: Failed to open input PDF file: 
   outputfile.pdf
   OWNER OR USER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Comment: use `qpdf` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the “input password”:

```
pdftk inputfile.pdf input_pw mypass output outputfile.pdf
```

`user_pw` is used for the output only.